# Can you declare your own function in Discord JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, discord, discord.js

Normally I just add to the command files or the index file easily but it's starting to look messy. Recently I got this leveling system working

```
if (!levels[message.author.id]) {
        levels[message.author.id] = {
            level: 1,
            exp: 0
        }   
    }

    // Gives random EXP
    let randomExp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 5);

    // Adds the random EXP to their current EXP
    levels[message.author.id].exp += randomExp;

    // Checks their EXP and changes their level
    for (x = 0; x < expLevels.length; x++) {
        if (levels[message.author.id].exp > expLevels[x]) {
            levels[message.author.id].level = x + 1;
            message.channel.reply(`congratulations! You reached level ${levels[message.author.id].level + 1}!`);
        }
    }
    
    fs.writeFile('./levels.json', JSON.stringify(levels), err => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    });
    
    if (levels[authorMessage.author.id].level >= 10) {
        message.member.roles.remove('720109209479413761');
        message.member.roles.add('719058151940292659');
    }
```

I would like to be able to put this into its own function and then call it in the "message" section for every time someone sends a message. Is that possible to do? Or no since I need to have access to the "message" variable?

I'm used to C++ with functions where it's much easier to deal with. Does anyone know if it's possible to code a bot in C++ or is there no support? If there is a way if someone can point me in the right direction to start please let me know. Otherwise I can easily stay with JS.

Comment: You can use [`aegis.cpp`](https://github.com/zeroxs/aegis.cpp) to make a Discord bot in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if a discord framework for C++ exists, probably but I'm not sure.

You can of course define a function somewhere and call it in the `onMessage` event.

There are two ways that you could do that.

- In the same file
- In another file

**Functions in the same file.**

You can declare a function and then pass arguments to that function. You don't need to declare the type of argument that is being passed here. [*Source*](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

```
function leveling(message) { // here you can include all parameters that you might need
// the rest of your code
}
```

Once you have a function you can call it like this.

```
leveling(message); // here we pass the values we need to the function
```

**Functions in a different file.**

The concept is the same, however we need to export the function in order to use it somewhere else. There are two ways to do this, either export only one function or export all functions, in the case of a dedicated functions file this is the easier option.

*Note: In this example I name the file `functions.js` and place it in the same directory as the file I require it from.*

```
module.exports = {
    // we need to declare the name first, then add the function
    leveling: function (message) { 
        // the rest of your code
    }
    // here we can add more functions, divided by a comma
}

// if you want to export only one function
// declare it normally and then export it
module.exports = leveling;
```

**Calling functions.**

To use this function we need to `require` it in the file we want to use it in. Here we also have two options.

Either require the whole file and get the function from there

```
const myfunctions = require('./functions.js'); // this is the relative path to the file
// get the function via the new constant
myfunctions.leveling(message);
```

Or use [Object destructuring](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/es6-syntax.html#object-destructuring) to get only what you need from the exported functions.

```
const { leveling } = require('./functions.js');

leveling(message);
```

Both of these options provide advantages and disadvantages but in the end they both do the same.

Comment: That was extremely detailed thank you so much. I’m assuming I did something wrong because I initially declared the function at the bottom in the same file. I declared it as “function levelSystem(authorMessage)” and passed “message”. Unfortunately that gave me an error because authorMessage isn’t anything. I’ll try as a separate file instead.

Comment: Ok so I did a separate file and I’m still getting message.channel.reply is not a function since it’s only really established in the “message” event.

Comment: Try to declare the function with `message` and not `authorMessage` then simply paste your existing code into the function. In regards to `message.channel.reply` not working. That's because you don't use channel when you reply. You only need that when you `send`. Example: `message.reply()` and `message.channel.send()`

Comment: Ah right I knew there was something weird looking there. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Yes it works now. I just have to fix how to display when someone levels up. That's the last thing that's getting me for right now lol